What is the name of this wing area?
What's the name of this wide area connecting the wing to the fuselage?



Does this wide area closest to the fuselage on some wing designs has a name?

Yes it does, but please note that you have two different kind of widenings in your pictures. In the first picture the widening goes backward, while in the second picture it goes forward.
The backward widening in the first picture is termed "Yehudi" and it is normally implemented on jetliners in order to accommodate the main landing gears and for other aerodynamic and structural reasons, as nicely explained in this answer:

The forward widening in the second picture is termed "leading-edge (root) extension" (aka "strake") or "chine". It basically works at "high angles of attack, generating a vortex flow over the inboard wing to stabilise the airflow and increase its speed locally, thus delaying the stall and also providing additional lift". This vortex generated by the strake is nicely visible in the following picture from this NASA report, where you see half of a wing being tested in a wind tunnel:

Strakes are mostly seen on jetfighters exactly for that reason but on the Rutan VariEze in your second picture they have been most probably implemented in order to:

increase the wing area and especially to increase it forward to shift the aerodynamic center forward as well, something which is always good in a canard design;
"increase directional stability, by reducing the adverse effects of crosswinds or yaw on the forward fuselage. Unlike a conventional fuselage, the chines allow the crossflow to travel smoothly over their profile and beyond, avoiding the side forces due to flow separation and stagnation";
improve stall characteristics; the downwash released by the canard interacts with the vorteces generated by the strakes (seen in the previous picture), further increasing wing lift at high AoA, something which is of paramount importance on a canard design where the canard is supposed to "stall" before the wing.


A VariEze being tested by NASA. The strakes are clearly visible from this perspective.

In the top example it's more of just a change in taper.

According to Boeing lore via George Schairer, yehudi's are named after Yehudi Menuhin, because no one could understand how the trailing edge extension improved the B-47 aerodynamics, just as no one could understand how Menuhin played the violin so well.

@sophit small increases in leading edge sweep on airliners are often referred to as "gloves".

It is called the wing root.
From Wikipedia:

The wing root is the part of the wing on a fixed-wing aircraft or winged-spaceship that is closest to the fuselage

It can also be used to describe the area right where the wing connects to the fuselage.
